# Transforming polynomials to a normalized form

Tags: algorithm, math

Does anybody know for equations of the form

2<sup>*n*</sup> + (–2)<sup>*n* – 1</sup> + ... + 2<sup>-*n*</sup> + (–2)<sup>–*n* + 1</sup> + ... = *y*

How to eliminate all the coefficient (not exponential) minuses?  I know what the *n*'s are, but I cannot calculate them to find *y*.

For example:

2<sup>4</sup> – 2<sup>2</sup> + 2 simplifies to 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>2</sup> + 2

or

2<sup>4</sup> – 2<sup>3</sup> + 2 – 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup> simplifies to 2<sup>3</sup> + 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>-1</sup> + 2<sup>-2</sup>

- *y* can be zero but never negative. That will be flagged as an error.
- All numbers are log<sub>2</sub>.
- The coefficient will always be either 1 or -1.
- No floats or rationals are allowed.

The purpose is that I want to save arrays of exponents (positive or negative) but not coefficients, and I need the polynomials to be in a normalized form for easy comparison.

Is there a name for this type of transformation?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can represent the positive elements in a binary representation of an integer and the same with the negative ones.  For example: `2^4 – 2^2 + 2` becomes `10010`(positive elements) and `00100`(negative elements).  Then substract the negative integer from the positive integer (you get `01110`, translated back: `2^3 + 2^2 + 2`)

Of course you will have to make sure you can hold all values (e.g. if you have components of 2^100, no built-in integer type will be sufficient -- you would need at least a 100-bit integer (larger if you have negative exponents, see below)).  At this point you can roll your own implementation (or find a BigInt library).

Also, you will have to keep track of which bit index represents which exponent -- in the above example it is trivial as all exponents were non-negative, but you need some shifting for negative exponents (e.g. `2^4 – 2^3 + 2 – 2^-1 + 2^-2` translates to `10010.01`(+) and `01000.10`(-), with the dot (`.`) representing the divide between non-negative and negative exponents; this then results in `01001.11` or `2^3 + 2^0 + 2^-1 + 2^-2`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an algorithm, just pick a negative term and convert: -2<sup>n</sup> => -2<sup>n+1</sup>+2<sup>n</sup>, then cancel out terms if possible (e.g. 2<sup>n+1</sup>-2<sup>n+1</sup> => 0). Repeat until there are no more negative terms.